# Adjoining square root of a square in a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I have to proof following

> ***Claim:*** Let $F$ be a field, $a \in F^\times, i \not \in F$ with $i^2 = a$. Then:
>   $$F[i] = F \oplus Fi \cong F[X]/(X^2-a) \text{ is a field } \Longleftrightarrow a \not \in (F^\times)^2.$$

I've proven the "$\Rightarrow$" direction (if the LHS is a field, then $(X^2-a)$ is a maximal ideal, hence $X^2-a$ is irreducible and so $a$ is not a square in $F$).

Now several things are not clear: first of all, how can we have the situation where $F[i]$ is not a field? We know that $i$ is algebraic over $F$ if and only if $F[i]$ is a field if and only if $F[i]=F(i)$ (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_element)). So if $F[i]$ is not a field then $i$ has to be transcendent over $F$, but that is not possible since it is a root of $X^2-a$!

I guess that this means that $F[i]$ is a division algebra, but on the other side it is strange that the polynomial $X^2-a$ (of degree 2) has four roots ($\pm 1$ and $\pm \sqrt(a)$ if $a$ is a square in $F$.

All the questions arose from 2.2.10 (p. 22) and from the proof of Theorem 5.4.4 (p. 68-69) of the book *Quaternion Algebras* of John Voight ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_element)).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For instance, "$\Bbb Q[2]$" (also known as $\Bbb Q[X]/(X^2-4)$, which makes $\pm2$ and $\pm X$ into four distinct square roots of $4$) is not a field because $(X-2)(X+2)=0$, so we have zero divisors. In fact, it's isomorphic to the ring $\Bbb Q^2$.

Comment: But isn't $\mathbb{Q}[2]$ the same as $\mathbb{Q}$? Or is this "2" like a "new element not lying in $\mathbb{Q}$ that happens to satisfy $2^2 = 4$"? If so, I got it, but I still see the problem with the equivalence coted in Wikipedia.

Comment: The material you quoted says that $F[i]$ is to be understood as $F[X]/(X^2-a)$. So $\mathbb Q[2]$ would be $\mathbb Q[X]/(X^2-4)$.  In other words, you're adjoining a new square root of 4, even though it already has a square root in your base field $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: The quote specifies $i\notin F$, so the adjoined $2$ is not the rational number $2$, but a polynomial variable.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I got it! But if $F[i]$ is not a field, shouldn't $i$ be transcendent, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_element)?

Comment: No, $i$ is not transcendental: it satisfies $i^2=a$ so it is algebraic over $F$.